# How to prevent attackers from doing many writes to the firestore database?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I already set security rules for my database, however there are still some places a user must be allowed to write to, but i am afraid an attacker might do multiple writes to the location, i can add an authentication check to allow write access but all they have to do is create an account to gain write access, the only other solution i can think of is only allowing a write to happen every X minutes, if that is possible, or is there another solution to prevent attackers from making multiple writes.

Comment: "*all they have to do is create an account to gain write access*" - yes, that's the way things work.  Your rules should determine **which** users can read and write specific data, or accept that anyone can read and write data by simply creating an account.  If you want general rate limiting, you should consider forcing your users through a backend endpoint that determine **when** that user is allow to write, if that's what you want.  You could use security rules for this, but there is no easy expression for this, and you're in for a lot of work to track write rates correctly.

Comment: @DougStevenson I see thanks, i think ill go for the backend solution with cloud functions as that makes the most sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting Doug Stevenson comment as community answer for better visibility:

"all they have to do is create an account to gain write access" - yes, that's the way things work. Your rules should determine which users can read and write specific data, or accept that anyone can read and write data by simply creating an account. If you want general rate limiting, you should consider forcing your users through a backend endpoint that determine when that user is allow to write, if that's what you want. You could use security rules for this, but there is no easy expression for this, and you're in for a lot of work to track write rates correctly.